# How can we copy a one file from Remote desktop to local machine using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, remote-desktop, vba

How would I copy a file from Remote desktop to a local machine using Excel VBA?

Comment: What drive or shared folder do you have mapped across the remote desktop connection? If it is a workbook that wants copying, a [Workbook.SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) should suffice.

Comment: Just so you know, "remote desktop" and "local machine" are just adding unneeded complexity to this question.  In essence you simply want to copy/save a file to a network location.  Think about it from the context of the file/script.

Comment: Additional thought: If you are actually trying to copy to the "local machine" regardless of what machine is connected, this is *significantly* more challenging.

Comment: i'm Not trying to make things complicated. I have a set of code which will take Disk space details of server. This code is written @ Remote server only. Everyday i'm taking the file(created by code)  and sending it. If i can make the destination file on to my local machine(Which is currently at server) i can extend my code to send an Outlook Mail also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can copy files between different computers/servers in VBA.  You didn't specify much so here is an example of coping from the local machine to a remote machine.  Just change the parameters for the copy (or move) for the reverse.

In my example I'm accessing the admin share 'Z$' on the remote machine.  You can specify any share name.

I tested this in Excel 2013.

```
Option Explicit 'always declare your vars!

Sub CopyFile()
    Dim FSO:           Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim strFile:       strFile = "c:\temp\RemoteCopyTest\mytestfile.txt"
    Dim strTargetPath: strTargetPath = "\\Server\Z$\"

    'verify the remote folder exists
    If FSO.FolderExists(strTargetPath) Then
        'verify the source file exists
        If FSO.FileExists(strFile) Then
            'use FSO.MoveFile <Source>,<Target> if you want to move instead of copy
            FSO.CopyFile strFile, strTargetPath
        Else
            MsgBox "ERROR:  Source FIle does not exist or is not accessible."
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "ERROR:  Target Folder does not exist or is not accessible."
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to your remote PC\ Server you have options to share resources ie if your using Remote Desktop Connection its Options\z Local Resources\ More\ Drives

You can pick your local c drive, which will now be available to you on remote machine... in Windows Explorer.

So when you run your Excel VBA you just have to move file from Remote to your local C drive listed on the remote machine (It may give it a new drive letter)

As DevilsAdvocate has said..its simply copying 1 file from here to there

BTW You can save your Remote Connection setup...so that its the same settings each time you connect to that PC/Server