# Can't CreateItemFromTemplate twice

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to create new email from a template using the following code.

```
Sub CreateEmailfromTemplate(ByVal email As String, ByVal pathToTemplate As String)
    Dim obApp As Object
    Dim NewMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set obApp = Outlook.Application
    'Change the template file folder path according to your case
    Set NewMail = obApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(pathToTemplate)
    With NewMail
        .To = email
    End With
    NewMail.Display

    Set obApp = Nothing
    Set NewMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

It works very well when I call it the first time. Yet when if I call it the second time it gives me bakc the `Runtime Error 462`: `Remote server does not exist or is not available`

the path I'm calling too is something like `"\\firefighter.eau\Work\CCL1\MTMA\Groupe Petty Officer\PEOPLE\MAILS\Demande d'attestation de recyclage.msg" : String : ModuleDeclarations.CreateEmail`

Comment: Could you tell us what line of code generates this error? I'm guessing it is `Set obApp = Outlook.Application`?

Comment: The many questions about this appear to be due to more than one version of a remote application being opened. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631641/run-time-error-462-the-remote-server-machine-does-not-exist-or-is-unavailable, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55956086/getting-remote-server-machine-does-not-exist-or-not-available-in-outlook-vbscr.

Answer (score 0):

> "\firefighter.eau\Work\CCL1\MTMA\Groupe Petty Officer\PEOPLE\MAILS\Demande d'attestation de recyclage.msg"

You need to download/copy the template locally and then use a local file as a template. A network path is not fully supported by Outlook.

See [How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/) for more information.

Comment: Ha, damn. I develop this macro on an excel sheet that is shared with everyone in my office. If I put his documents locally people will not be able to access them. No way to call them on the server?

Comment: I'm interested! From what you say it seems to be the only way!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34451904/how-can-we-copy-a-one-file-from-remote-desktop-to-local-machine-using-excel-vba